# How to specify lib folder for JARs when using Android-generated ant build file?

Tags: xml, android, ant, build

Im using an ant build file that has been generated by android. Our Android application requires a JAR file that lives inside the lib folder of our project, so I need to adjust the classpath that ant is using when it builds stuff.

When I run:

```
ant -lib lib debug
```

the project builds just fine, but this should really be inside the build file itself. The build file that android generates references the android_rules.xml so a lot of this stuff is automated. I guess my question, what the best practice here when working with the Android build rules ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Our Android application requires a JAR
>   file that lives inside the lib folder
>   of our project

Put it in the `libs/` folder, and everything will work automatically. I do not know what in your application could possibly require the `lib/` directory instead of `libs/`.

Comment: Moved everything to libs and removed the lib folder. No longer need to use -lib parameter to ant. Builds just fine. Thanks.