# How to resolve javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, jaxb

In my Android app I use:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
```

But I get:

> `The import javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved`

I do have `com.viewstreet.java.eclipse.jaxbplugin.JAXBPlugin` in my plugins list.

Comment: Use simple XML instead. Jaxb requires libraries that android does nit include. So I wrote a blog post about simple in android to help with this common problem: http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Comment: Please do not re-post; I've merged the 3 times you asked this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the JAR in the project's `libs/` directory, then add it to the build path via the Add JARs button. That's my standard recipe, and it seems to work, and it has the advantage of putting the JAR in the right spot for command-line builds as well.

At this point, though, I suspect that you will get a compile error. Generally, you cannot import classes in the `java` and `javax` packages into an Android project.

Answer (score 17):

@commonsware is correct , just add respctive JAXB API jars in lib folder of your projet or in case of maven project **add dependency in pom file**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

viz in my case on linux, solved the issue

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/ and download the standalone distribution (link at the very bottom of page).
2. **jaxb-ri-2.3.1.zip** or whatever version is the latest shall be downloaded. Unzip it and copy the **jaxb-ri\mod\jaxb-api.jar** from the unzipped folder into the **plugins** folder of your eclipse installation directory.
3. Go to eclipse, open your project, right click project name in Projects panel (left most) and choose **Properties** => **Build Path**
4. Under **Libraries** tab, select **Classpath** and then click **Add External JARs** button. Browse and select the file you just copied to eclipse's plugins folder.
5. Click **Apply and Close**

Just import your required javax.xml.bind classes and your project shall be built instantly.

Answer (score 4):

Download `jax-b.jar` and add it as external jar in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Any `import cannot be resolved` in Java means a class you referenced is not found anywhere on the classpath.  You need the library you're trying to use added to your classpath.  In Eclipse, that's in project properties in the Java Build Path => Libraries tab.  If you don't have the jar file that contains the API you're trying to use, you probably need to get it from http://jaxb.java.net/.

Comment: I did download JAXB2_20110412.jar and added it to my project's Java Build Path, but nothing changed... :-(

Comment: @Marcos, reading from the website it says you need to double click on the jar you downloaded.  The REAL jars you need are inside the jar -- when you double click on it, you'll be asked to accept a license agreement.  When you click accept, it will extract everything into a jaxb directory.  Inside that, there's a lib directory with jaxb-api.jar which is probably the one you actually need in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: Followed the instructions literally, no change... :-(

Comment: Sorry, my mistake of youth... ;-)