# How to resolve javax.xml.bind.* imports in Eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resolve javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849638/how-to-resolve-javax-xml-bind-jaxbcontext-in-eclipse)

How to resolve javax.xml.bind.* imports in Eclipse?
Adding JAXB2_20110412.jar to my project's Java Build Path => Libraries tab as "external jar" did not change the "unresolved..." errors...