# Android + Jsoup - Having problems parsing HTML

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

Basically, I have a large string of HTML. Inside, I have a span of class 'pageHeader'. I am having a ton of trouble just getting the app to open with the Jsoup parts added, let laone using the parsed parts of the HTML. To start, here are my imports:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

After I get string `html` which is basically just one long string of HTML, I try to parse the document in my `onCreate` method:

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element span = doc.select("span.pageHeader").first();
    String text = span.attr("InnerText");
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've tried a few other things, but they're all mainly variants of that approach. It always crashes the emulator despite no viewable errors in Eclipse.

Comment: There must be some error/exceptions shown in logcat, whenever your app crash. Post logcat will help people investigate your problem.

Comment: Here's the main error it seems: 04-01 23:55:43.677: E/AndroidRuntime(315): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup

Comment: What SDK version are you using? If using r17, make sure the jsoup.jar is in the libs directory.

Comment: Pretty sure it's r17. I only downloaded it around 2 weeks ago and that looks to be the latest version. jsoup-1.6.2.jar is in the 'Referenced Libraries' directory. Should it be somewhere else?

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I just manually added the JAR before. I used the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3642953/1103669) to correctly add the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported the directory incorrectly. If anyone has a similar problem (doubt it but oh well), refer to the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642953/1103669).