# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Exception stack trace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at com.amphisoft.mebox.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:167)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at com.amphisoft.mebox.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  695):    ... 4 more

This is my code:

```
protected User doInBackground(User... user) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("username", user[0].username);
            parameters.put("password", user[0].password);
            String response = HTTPUtil.post("/user/login.json", parameters,
                    null);
            System.out.println("Response:" + response);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            User userObj = gson.fromJson(response, User.class);
            Store.getInstance().user = userObj;

        }
```

I tried adding gson-2.1jar many times in the library.. But getting the same error as class definition not found.. Please help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Next time it'd be great if you posted _full_ logs and code.

Comment: @user942821: Thanks for the comment, I will make sure from next time onwards i will put the logs and code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `libs` folder and put *gson* in there, then add the folder to the library path.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I did that, it was working fine. Then i found that I was using network through proxy. So I had to set proxy in my emulator. Not its working fine. Thanks