# No DataTypeConverter Method option in android

Tags: java, android

I want to use **DataTypeConverter.printBase64Binary(.........)** in my project.
But there is no option coming through intellisense. Am i missing some jar ?

Comment: have you imported javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter? if this is not an issue try Window -> Preferences -> Java/Editor/Content Assist and select your likings

Comment: I tried to import import javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter; .But a error is prompting "Create class DataTypeConverter class".

Comment: i tried to add jaxb-api-2.2.jar .when i compiled my project i get this error <br/> [2012-10-16 15:48:07 - DistimoApp] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/bind/Binder.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

Comment: its working .i follow this article ...awesome    [Add a third party jar in android and make it delvik converted jar ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

Answer (score 4):

you can use this methods.
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3'

and i use android.util.Base64 for Android

incompatible / replacement

```
DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary 
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());




DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(finalData);
android.util.Base64.encodeToString(finalData, 16) 



DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encodedInitialData);
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());
```

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342136/alternatives-a-datatypeconverter-in-androidsolved)

Comment: it works for me for scribd java support for convert data type in android Pie API 28

Answer (score 2):

Android API provides Base64 to do the conversions you are looking for.  However, I used Apache Codec as a compatibility library between different platforms for the client library to get around this issue.