# Alternatives for DatatypeConverter in Android

Tags: java, android, aes

I trying implement algorithm AES 128 in Android but it doesn't work, the problem is `import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;`

`DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(key)`
 and
`DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(finalData)`

Does an alternative exist?

**My method:**

```
private static final String ALGORIT = "AES";

public static String encryptHackro(String plaintext, String key)
throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
BadPaddingException, IOException, DecoderException {


    byte[] raw = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(key);

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITMO);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes(""));
    byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(iv);
    outputStream.write(cipherText);

    byte[] finalData = outputStream.toByteArray();

    String encodedFinalData = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(finalData);

    return encodedFinalData;

}
```

I see others [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109970/alternative-of-datatypeconverter-printhexbinarybyte-array-and-datatypeconver), but I can't implement a solution.

Comment: Why can't you use the given alternative? What problems did you run into?

Comment: the encryption result it's diferent

Comment: Then you did something wrong. You should show what you tried.

Comment: yea, i use         'byte[] raw = Base64.decodeBase64(key)'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Solution**

I solved my problem using

```
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3'
```

and I use android.util.Base64 for Android

**incompatible** / **replacement**

```
DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary 
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());




DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(finalData);
android.util.Base64.encodeToString(finalData, 16) 



DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encodedInitialData);
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());
```

Comment: Commons-codec 1.3 is not part of the Android API.  What happens if Google changes the version of commons-codec in future versions of Android?    It's just coincidence it works as version 1.3 just happens to match the version in Android's root class loader..     The case I'm trying to solve is when the base64 decode is used in a pure Java sub-project that is included into an Android App.  It is very annoying of Google this..

Comment: This is not a reliable solution

Comment: I solved using implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.1'

Comment: Why not use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` ?

Answer (score 6):

In case you are looking to use DatatypeConverter like me in android please add this to build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
```

This will add DatatypeConverter.

Comment: Note that you must supply your own implementation (such as Xerces); Android does not ship with a default implementation. To add 'xerces' in android project use this dependency: implementation("xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.0") Source: mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.0