# Import SwingX jar library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I've followed the step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse), but I still got an error. Here is the screenshot of the error. [image]

So what did I miss and what should I do to avoid this error: "The type [org.jdesktop.swingx.JXPanel](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXPanel.html) cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download [SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/download/releases/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar) and to add the jar into project's classpath

Comment: Thank you! So I've just downloaded the wrong jar file. It works now!

Comment: Too old AMHO, try to use JavaFX. ;-)