# android getting java lang verify error when using external java lib

Tags: java, android, verifyerror, lang

i am using a external library in my android project getting javalang verify error when calling the class where that library imported, it is java.jxl library

any help please I created a directory called lib inside my library project and then referred it in the library. And this library is linked with the original android app.

also i getting below info

```
11-16 18:12:40.230: W/dalvikvm(14253): VFY: unable to resolve static method 260: Ljxl/Workbook;.getWorkbook (Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljxl/Workbook;
11-16 18:12:40.230: D/dalvikvm(14253): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000c
11-16 18:12:40.230: W/dalvikvm(14253): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 124 (Ljxl/read/biff/BiffException;)
11-16 18:12:40.230: W/dalvikvm(14253): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x11
11-16 18:12:40.230: W/dalvikvm(14253): VFY:  rejected Lcom/kd/hockymain/Kdexcel;.getfile ()V
11-16 18:12:40.230: W/dalvikvm(14253): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0011
11-16 18:12:40.230: W/dalvikvm(14253): VFY:  rejected Lcom/kd/hockymain/Kdexcel;.getfile ()V
11-16 18:12:40.230: W/dalvikvm(14253): Verifier rejected class Lcom/kd/hockymain/Kdexcel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries should be put in the `libs/` directory (not `lib/`, note the trailing slash). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643015/315306).

This will convert the compiled libraries code to the Dalvik format, and will provide the symbols definitions for Eclipse to work.

Comment: great, 
the answer from ur link amazing it solved my problem completely, I should find that link before, Thank u lot