# How to resolve the java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I'm trying to read the xlsx file from asset folder. I received below exception,

> 05-16 10:12:05.613: E/AndroidRuntime(2915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       05-16 10:12:05.613: E/AndroidRuntime(2915): java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

before this exception, I received some warnings also like,

- > Could not find method 
  >   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorkbookDocument$Factory.parse,
  >   referenced from method
  >   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead
- > VFY: unable to resolve exception class 3612
  >   (Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException;)

I have added poi 3.12 library on my application, libraries screenshot as below,

[image]

And I have checked poi-3.12 and poi-ooxml-3.12 jar files in Order and Export, screenshot as below,

[image]

I used below code,

```
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("sample.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
        String value = cell.getStringCellValue() + "";
```

I want to read and write the .XLSX and .XLS files. How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you have the option to check the deployable for the android? Just to check that the needed jars are there?

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP There is no separate jar files for Android development.

Comment: goto your bin file and delete the files there, re-add to the build path clean and rebuild. maybe it might help

Comment: where does the error occur? Phone or emulator? Or both?

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP Both emulator and Phone.

Comment: @bharath did you find any solution for xlsx?

Comment: @Meenaxi I tried lot of ways. But didn't find any solutions. I'm used .xls file for my application.

Comment: @bharath i found the solution see the example here https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX. Just need to add this 2 jar files aa-poi-3.10-min-0.1.5.jar and aa-poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-more-0.1.5.jar

Answer (score 5):

Firs you should connect to your project these jars.

[image: jars you need]

Then use this code for reading

```
public static void readXLSXFile() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:/Test.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

        XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row; 
        XSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext())
        {
            row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext())
            {
                cell=(XSSFCell) cells.next();

                if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                {
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                }
                else if(cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Already I have added those jar files in project build libraries.

Comment: Can you tell please your ide?

Comment: I'm using eclipse IDE.

Comment: So, try to remove all libraries and than connect again only these 4 jars. Maybe you have some duplication.

Comment: If it doesn't work, download these 2 jars, and try with them. https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX/tree/master/libs

Comment: Yeah I tried lot of times. But no use.  AndroidReadXLSX is only for read XLSX file. We cant write XLSX file.

Comment: I also had a lot of problems when I've been working with this library, but I needed hust read the file. A know that these libraries work fine in java (not android). You should change jar files, and remove from libraries classes wich you don't use.

Comment: Also you can just write a server in java (without android), and make your processing there.

Comment: Above code is working fine in Java application. But same code is not working in Android.

Comment: Ya, I know. My Scientific Adviser told me that it is impossible work with this library in android, it also does not work with appcompat correctly. The best way is writing a server.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code to able to read and write the .XLSX and .XLS files

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("sample.xlsx"));
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
String value = cell.getStringCellValue() + "";
```

For your libraries, please have a look here [android getting java lang verify error when using external java lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415167/android-getting-java-lang-verify-error-when-using-external-java-lib)