# Creating xslx-file with Android

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I want to create a xslx-File in my Android Application. Im Using Apache poi-ooxml-3.12.jar for it. But while calling the XSSFWorkbook Constructor I get the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
```

This is my Code:

```
Workbook workbook;

    if (StringOperationsUtil.getFileExtension(file).equalsIgnoreCase("XLSX")){
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    } else  { 
        //default xls
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    }
```

There is another Question about the topic out there ([How to create .docx files and .xlsx files on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877532/how-to-create-docx-files-and-xlsx-files-on-android)) but there is no correct for me solution in it. Also the apache team didn't answer me. I can't believe that it's not possible to create the newest excel file in an android application. Does really any Android Developer is not using xlsx files? I really can't believe this. I'm using Android Studio btw.

Please let me know, if you guys know something about that issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A previous question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272103/how-to-resolve-the-java-lang-verifyerror-org-apache-poi-xssf-usermodel-xssfwork

Comment: Nope didnt. I already tried that out. This may be work in Eclipse but not in Android Studio.... :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is incompatibility between the poi-ooxml .jar files and your Android OS.

I would definitely revisit this link first, carefully double-checking *everything* discussed:

[How to resolve the java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272103/how-to-resolve-the-java-lang-verifyerror-org-apache-poi-xssf-usermodel-xssfwork)

If that doesn't work, your "Plan B" might be [dx](http://wing-linux.sourceforge.net/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#dx):

[Android java.lang.VerifyError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror)

Finally, it might even be an issue with ADT (although this link was for Eclipse, and you're using Android Studio):

[Java.lang.verifyerror how do I fix or even find out the root cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764584/java-lang-verifyerror-how-do-i-fix-or-even-find-out-the-root-cause)