# Could not find class 'com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream'

Tags: android, xstream

Im using XStream jar file in android project from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/xstream-for-android/downloads/detail?name=xstream-for-android-1.0.0.zip&can=2&q=).

Im getting this exception

> Could not find class 'com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream'

at this line `XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());`

i followed this link to solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643015/341443 but not working.

Please let me know how to solve this issue or any thing im missing here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is done by somebody and given to me for further implementation.

So, After so much headache, i find that the project contains Android Private Library which includes XStream jar file. You can see below image

[image]

i fix this issue by check the Android Private Library in Order and Export. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596990/341443) helped me to solve this issue.
Hope it saves somebody time ....

[image]