# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jersey

I have searched a lot for this exception, none of the threads helped me.

I got this exception:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;
```

I got this exception when I added jersey jars to my 'libs' in android

#### something weird

when I delete this jar `jersey-core-1.17`, the exception goes but I start to get another exception when is classdefnotfound exception.

I added the jars in libs folder and I added them in java bath configuration.

I tried clean and rebuild and delete bin and gen folders and restart eclipse and restart windows but nothing word

please help

#### note

i added my jars using this question [Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project) , also i added more jars in previous projects using that question and it works good, so i don't think the problem in adding jars, right?

#### also

check there is no this single on the jar

[image]

#### edit

[image]

Comment: Which class is named in the exception?  Is it a ClassNotFoundException, or a NoClassDefError?

Comment: @nitind before i didn't remember but now it is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Build `

Comment: myabe because I accedently removed , the android dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your other jar files also has `MultivaluedMap` in it. You are going to have to search through those jars and remove any duplicates.

Looking through [findJar.com](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html), it is probably `jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar`. Open it with WinZip and remove the `javax\ws\rs\core\MultiValuedMap.class` file, save the jar, and replace the new version in your `libs` folder.

Comment: yes i found this fuc.... class, as u said, it has the same name, but why should I remove it from `jsr` not from the second one ?

Comment: OK, remove it from the second one. Just don't have two copies of it. It makes no difference where you remove it from.

Comment: you are the one. I THANK YOU . please can I take ur email for another exception ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that somehow you have the same class in different lib files. Are you sure you don't have overlapping jars?

Comment: no no no i dont have any thing except libs folder please help

Comment: I don't know what happened, the excpetion goes, let me check if the second exception still

Comment: Well, you can have duplicate class files in those libs folder. Not the same package/jar, but those jars could contain the same classes internally. Especially because you have so many, I really think that's the case.

Comment: I always use this all jar all together, :(