# how to re add android dependencies again

Tags: android

i in wrong (accedently) removed the android dependencies, please how to add it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, try right-clicking on the project and selecting "Android Tools/Fix Project Properties"

Comment: it works but I got this exception again Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;

Comment: Try deleting the /gen/ and /bin/ folders and cleaning the project. This problem is also described here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Comment: I have checked that questions millions of time before , it didn't help me :(((((((((

Comment: I think I answered your original question about dependencies though... :)

Comment: I have already did here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903009/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-ljavax-ws-rs-core-multivaluedma

Comment: please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966656/android-bitmap-isnt-created-from-base64

Answer (score 0):

project-right click-properties-go to  BuildPath-libraries-AddLibrary-android classpath container-next and finish