# FTP client Android

Tags: android, ftp

I am working on a project where I need to access FTP server using its domain, username and password. I want to save data

This is my code, but it does not work. I'm using the Apache Commons FTP Library. Can you help me?
Thank you!

```
 FTPClient client = new FTPClient(); 

            try {
            client.connect("1.2.3.4");
            client.login("USERNAME", "PASSWORD"); 
                String filename = "file1.txt"; 
                FileInputStream fis = null; 
                    fis = new FileInputStream(filename); 
                    client.storeFile(filename, fis); 
                    client.logout(); 
                    fis.close();



        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.i("tag", "SocketException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            Log.i("tag", "IOException");
        }
```

Error:

```
could not find class 'org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient'
```

Comment: try this :http://myexperiencewithandroid.blogspot.in/2012/09/ftp-client-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

If think that you have that error because you didn't import that library to your project.

Here you have tutorial to that : [Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: Read that : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: 08-02 12:47:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(925): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
08-02 12:47:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(925): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
08-02 12:47:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at com.example.test2.MainActivity.getScreen(MainActivity.java:94)
08-02 12:47:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at com.example.test2.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:57)
08-02 12:47:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at com.example.test2.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:48)
08-02 12:47:33.727: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)