# Hi.while developing OCR application in Android i'm getting Error as "Unfortunately OCR test has stopped" in Android emulator

Tags: java, android, ocr

i've been developing OCR application in Android.while running the app in Emulator  i'm getting Error as "Unfortunately OCR test has stopped".so can any one plz help me to resolve the error...Thanks in advance....

The Logcat:

```
08-26 14:24:45.128: D/dalvikvm(548): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
08-26 14:24:47.988: D/LanguageCodeHelper(548): getOcrLanguageName: eng->English
08-26 14:24:48.008: D/LanguageCodeHelper(548): getTranslationLanguageName: es->Spanish
08-26 14:24:48.219: D/dalvikvm(548): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 6% free 6680K/7047K, paused 8ms+7ms
08-26 14:24:48.319: W/dalvikvm(548): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;
08-26 14:24:48.319: D/AndroidRuntime(548): Shutting down VM
08-26 14:24:48.319: W/dalvikvm(548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.initOcrEngine(CaptureActivity.java:715)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:372)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:46)
08-26 14:24:48.369: E/AndroidRuntime(548):  ... 17 more
08-26 14:33:18.479: D/LanguageCodeHelper(576): getOcrLanguageName: eng->English
08-26 14:33:18.489: D/LanguageCodeHelper(576): getTranslationLanguageName: es->Spanish
08-26 14:33:18.708: D/dalvikvm(576): GC_CONCURRENT freed 263K, 6% free 6682K/7047K, paused 7ms+6ms
08-26 14:33:18.809: W/dalvikvm(576): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;
08-26 14:33:18.809: D/AndroidRuntime(576): Shutting down VM
08-26 14:33:18.809: W/dalvikvm(576): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.initOcrEngine(CaptureActivity.java:715)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:372)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:46)
08-26 14:33:18.838: E/AndroidRuntime(576):  ... 17 more
08-26 14:33:23.109: I/Process(576): Sending signal. PID: 576 SIG: 9
08-26 15:31:18.949: D/LanguageCodeHelper(732): getOcrLanguageName: eng->English
08-26 15:31:18.969: D/LanguageCodeHelper(732): getTranslationLanguageName: es->Spanish
08-26 15:31:19.189: D/dalvikvm(732): GC_CONCURRENT freed 241K, 6% free 6680K/7047K, paused 7ms+6ms
08-26 15:31:19.289: W/dalvikvm(732): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;
08-26 15:31:19.289: D/AndroidRuntime(732): Shutting down VM
08-26 15:31:19.299: W/dalvikvm(732): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.initOcrEngine(CaptureActivity.java:715)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:372)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:46)
08-26 15:31:19.319: E/AndroidRuntime(732):  ... 17 more
08-26 15:31:24.919: I/Process(732): Sending signal. PID: 732 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: and the activity code please...

Answer (score 2):

The error is occuring at:

```
edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity.initOcrEngine(CaptureActivity.java:715)
```

*ie* line 715 of class `CaptureActivity`. Furthermore, the cause listed in the log (towards the end) is that it could start a library to initiate the class TessBaseAPI.

Assuming that there are no errors when you are writing your code in eclipse, then a likely cause is that a library you are using isn't be added to the all when it is sent to the phone or emulator. To solve this, you need to edit the project properties to include the libraries you have added to the project. See [Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project).

Comment: This is my code in CaptureActivity at line 715 ' baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();'