# Android: Access class from a Jar file

Tags: android, class, jar

I've downloaded a .Jar file called Dexmaker.

**Problem** : If I call classes from this Jar file, I get errors. How to invoke classes from this jar ?

**What I've done so far**:

Ensured that the Build path is correct. Jar is in the libs folder, and all sources are checked. This Jar is placed on top, so that it is compiled first.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: <class> cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Is the class public and did you try to import it?

Comment: Class is supposed to be public as per a tutorial. But how do I import a Jar file ?

Comment: I tried adding it to my project it allowed me to call DexMaker class.

Comment: The code is as simple as this: 

Dexmaker dex = new dexmaker();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42944/discussion-between-apoorv-and-abhishek)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this great reply by Russ Bateman on how to add a Jar to an Android project:

[Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

As for me, I was using the wrong jar in my project. Thanks to Apoorv for pointing it out.