# NoClassDefException for Java third-party libraries under Android

Tags: android

I found this [Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project) and followed the directions there, but I still seem to be getting a NoClassDefException on my class derived from the third party library.

I downloaded the third party library and imported according to the answer above. According to this, it will convert the code automatically to dalvik. Then, when I run on my phone, it tells me it cannot instantiate the sub-class of the third party library. Other messages say it is because it cannot find the superclass.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the "libs" directory is a magic name. I renamed my directory to libs and re-ran the app and it appears to be working.

Comment: `libs/` is a very magic name. Also, step #5 of the accepted answer on the question you linked to is wrong. That being said, you may need to double-check the "Order & Export" portion of your build path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990