# Create a jar from a package and add it as library in a project

Tags: java, android

I am working on an existing `android project`. I want to create a `jar` file from a package of that project and add that as a `library`. (i.e. i have 5 packages in that project, i want to create a jar from one of those packages and add that package as library). As I am new to java and android, i could not understand what will be the best approach for achieving above goal. thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project

Comment: @developer known as Insane, thanks for pointing this

Answer (score 1):

Create Jar File:
 -

```
   1. Select package from package explorer. 
   2. Go to File -> Export -> Create Java -> Jar File.
   3. Perform wizard steps.
```

Add jar file to Project.
 -

```
Now put this created jar file in to libs folder of the Project and add it to build path.`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Eclipse then right click

```
Package Name> Export >Java >JAR file
```

and then you can add this jar file in your libs and use it wherever you want