# eclipse for android . able to run but unable to view

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have encountered a problem which is i'm able to start the application in the emulator however nth is being displayed . please help

**this is my logcat**

```
04-21 22:44:37.070: D/dalvikvm(863): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)

04-21 22:44:38.160: E/dalvikvm(863): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries', referenced from method com.example.chartproject.MainActivity.getIntent

04-21 22:44:38.160: W/dalvikvm(863): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1122 (Lorg/achartengine/model/CategorySeries;) in Lcom/example/chartproject/MainActivity;

04-21 22:44:38.160: D/dalvikvm(863): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007

04-21 22:44:38.210: D/dalvikvm(863): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x21f7 at 0x0b in Lcom/example/chartproject/MainActivity;.getIntent

04-21 22:44:38.210: D/dalvikvm(863): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x21fa at 0x14 in Lcom/example/chartproject/MainActivity;.getIntent

04-21 22:44:38.210: D/dalvikvm(863): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2201 at 0x20 in Lcom/example/chartproject/MainActivity;.getIntent

04-21 22:44:38.210: D/dalvikvm(863): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x21fc at 0x32 in Lcom/example/chartproject/MainActivity;.getIntent

04-21 22:44:39.370: D/gralloc_goldfish(863): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: self explanatory: Could not find class org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries. Are you using a library?

Comment: yes i'm using achartengine jar

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you haven't add the library archartengine.jar correctly in your project.
Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643015/1503155) to add your library, clean your project and try again.