# Open source License in Android App

Tags: android

We have an android application and are using some third party licenses. What is the best place to include these licenses in the app? In iOS we include it in the setting bundle, but I am not sure the best place to do so in android.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Do you mean third party library ?

Comment: yes third party libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my apps I generally place the license .txt file in the **assets** directory. Read the **Github** (I generally use library from github) page thoroughly about licencing. Notify the **original creator** about the use of his library. Then, if the product is of a client I will ask if to include the creator with link in the about section(if there is one). In my own apps I will include the link and author in the about section somewhere in my app.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the step-by-step:**

- *Download the library to your host development system.*
- *Create a new folder, libs, in your `Eclipse/Android project`.*
- *Right-click libs and choose `Import -> General -> File System`, then
  `Next`, Browse in the filesystem to find the library's parent directory
  (i.e.: where you downloaded it to).*
- *Click OK, then click the directory name (not the checkbox) in the
  left pane, then check the relevant JAR in the right pane. This puts
  the library into your project (physically).*
- *Right-click on your project, choose `Build Path -> Configure Build
  Path`, then click the `Libraries tab`, then Add `JARs...`, navigate to
  your new JAR in the libs directory and add it. (This, incidentally,
  is the moment at which your new JAR is converted for use on Android.)*

**NOTE**

Step 5 may not be needed, if the lib is already included in your build path. Just ensure that its existence first before adding it.

This is also explained at [adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project).

Comment: But he is talking about where the licenses have to be included. Not about how include a library. Right?

Comment: I asked OP in the comment. Check his reply above. I also upvoted that comment because `"that comment adds something useful to the post"` as it clears confusions.

Comment: I thought @VedPrakash was asking if I am talking about third part library licenses. I am aware of adding third party libraries, but wanted to know what is the best practice to give credit for the third party source, libraries, etc in an android app