# Missing Parse.class

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I keep getting the following error despite having imported the *Parse* JAR file into my project. Is there anyway that I could resolve this? Thanks a lot!

> Source not found: The source attachment does not contain the source for
>   the file Parse.class

```
// Compiled from Parse.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class com.parse.Parse {

  // Field descriptor #249 Ljava/lang/String;
  private static final java.lang.String TAG = "com.parse.Parse";

  // Field descriptor #252 Landroid/content/Context;
  static android.content.Context applicationContext;

  // Field descriptor #249 Ljava/lang/String;
  static java.lang.String applicationId;

  // Field descriptor #249 Ljava/lang/String;
  static java.lang.String clientKey;

  // Field descriptor #256 I
  public static final int LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE = 2;

  // Field descriptor #256 I
  public static final int LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG = 3;
```

Comment: This error you get when you compile/execute some code of your project on eclipse? Or when you trying to see a source of a dependent library used by your code? If is number 1 case, you must go to run -> Run Configuration in your eclipse and then -> Classpath. Then, just add your dependent JAR to your code execution enviroment.

Comment: See these links : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project & https://www.parse.com/questions/adding-android-support-v4jar-lib-and-v7-appcompat