# Deleted android-support-v7-appcompat from package mistakenly, how to restore it

Tags: android, eclipse

I deleted android-support-v7-appcompat from eclipse package explorer mistakenly and now i can see lots of error in my project.
How can i restore it ? I am stuck, please assist me.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include android-support-v7-appcompat again to your workspace you can find it from here.

```
<sdk>\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
```

and include it to your project like this.

Right-click on your project, select Properties
Click on `Android` 
Scroll down and click `Add...` and select your app compact lib.
Click ok. cleaqn and build you are good to go.

Comment: From where i can get this : android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: ? where is the screenshot.?

Comment: I am re-installing everything now