# How to import barcodescanner project from GitHub to Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I found this project in GitHub [ClickHere:](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) I want to import it from GitHub to eclipse. I downloaded zip and unzip. I already had gradle and grdale plugin in eclipse. I create local.properties file in root directory of project barcodescanner-master with path to android-sdk. In cmd from root directory of project i run

```
gradle eclipse
```

but i have error

```
Task eclipse not found in root project barcodescanner-master
```

I guess i have to add

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

somewhere in build.gradle file. But i don't know where.
If i add in first line of gradle.build i have this error

`Task eclipse not found in project barcodescanner. Some candidates are: 'eclipse`'

It looks little bit differ. Addition is Some candidates are: 'eclipse'

Please help me. Thank you

UPDATE:

As wrote Ceiling Gecko I try to "Import Gradle Project". First time i got error. But then I use Gradle Wraper and everething went fine. As a result i have many gradle projects in Eclipse. But i can't run gradle project as android application.

UPDATE 2:

1) I intall gradle.

2) Downloaded project

3) Unzip

4) In project root from cmd run "gradle build"

5) Add

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'
```

to build.gradle

5) In project root from cmd run "gradle eclipse"

Everything is Success
Now when I try to File - import - Existing Android Code Into Workspace - next - browse to project root
I see this

[image: What i've got]

Many android projects and I don't know what to choose.

Kind regards.

Comment: What happens when you try to just "Import Gradle Project" in Eclipse and build the model?

Comment: I have this in Console
`Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Program Files\eclipse\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip`
i'll try this now and write what happens then

Comment: there is no file C:\Program Files\eclipse\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties. Where i have to set gradle version?

Comment: This project in Github doesn't exists (404 error)

Comment: Thanks to moderator, who edit my question)))
https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this library:

- https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing

You need to download it and put to your project.

Comment: How can I add this library to my project? Just copy the files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project -- this might help you.