# url link for downloading apache commons-net library

Tags: java, android, apache, apache-commons-net

I want to get the date and time from NTP server and i'm unsuccessful to download the library. I downloaded the files from this link but non of the file seems to be a library. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi
I also downloaded a jar from this link and added in my project  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjxjv7phkb8xfhh/commons-net-3.1.jar but still the errors in my project does'nt disappered. 
Please give my any easy downloading link and explain how to use it in the application.

Comment: check this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachecommonsnetjar.htm

Comment: Your question is not very clear on what problem you really have.     Use maven/gradle etc to fetch files. Or download from repo. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download from the first link the .zip binary and extract the .jar file.
Then you have to add that to your project:

**ANDROID STUDIO**

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library?answertab=votes#tab-top)

**ECLIPSE**

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project?answertab=votes#tab-top)