# Android Unable to Import Library project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I read almost every answer obout this topi c but i cannot find a working solution for my case or maybe I'm missing somthing.
I use eclipse as IDE and I would like to use an external library for example I'm trying to add [this Library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/159) to my project but I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.
I tried download the full project and import it into the workspace, mark it as library and then under my project and add it as reference. 
If everything is ok how should I call an activity from the linke library?
I tried to defind the linked activity into my manifest file but without success.

Could you please point me in the right way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code which will call the library activity inside onCreate() or any other method which you choose like

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity);
//Here you need to call directory chooser activity.
    final Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(this, DirectoryChooserActivity.class);

    final DirectoryChooserConfig config = DirectoryChooserConfig.builder()
            .newDirectoryName("DirChooserSample")
            .allowReadOnlyDirectory(true)
            .allowNewDirectoryNameModification(true)
            .build();

    chooserIntent.putExtra(DirectoryChooserActivity.EXTRA_CONFIG, config);
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Import `DirectoryChooserActivity` and `DirectoryChooserConfig` class in your activity; If you are not able to import the mentioned class then you are not added library into the project correctly.

Comment: Do I need to import the whole project or only the libs from the library?

Comment: Try the demo project which is available in https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser/tree/master/sample

Comment: Library is enough. Follow the step which is described https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser/blob/master/README.md

Comment: thank you guys, I'm sorry but I guess I'm doing somehting wrong importing the library :-( If I try to import the library from github it cannot be reference as library

Comment: Even if the library seems to be linked correctly I cannot import : import net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserActivity;
import net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.DirectoryChooserConfig;

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project

Comment: Still no luck :-( project inmported and marked as library, but import does not work , what Am I missing?

Comment: Could someone just help me to import the library in the correct way?

Comment: I guess I should give up after trying for a whole day :-(