# Map Fragment Crashes Application

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

In my Eclipse I created a new application.

Just for testing purposes I put a `Fragment` in XML and left the code unchanged. But still my application is crashing. I've tried help from other questions but everyone is doing something like switching tabs and changing navigation.

So far I just want an empty Map Fragment. Don't even want to show the Map yet.

#### Code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res    /android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### LogCat

03-07 01:0

```
8:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687): Process: com.example.testtt, PID: 6687
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testtt/com.example.testtt.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:315)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at com.example.testtt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     ... 11 more
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4822)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     ... 21 more
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn''t find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testtt-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testtt-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
03-07 01:08:54.174: E/AndroidRuntime(6687):     ... 24 more
```

It should at least show me the empty `SupportMapFragment` when I run the app but it's crashing.

Comment: [logcat](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-log-class-api-to-debug-android-application-code.html) or it didn't happen.

Comment: @zapl added the Logcat in Question sorry i dont get the proper methord to put logcat in
But it says :

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment`

Comment: have you added google play services to your project?

Comment: yes i have Added them google play services in my project.. But i dont need them because i dont want to show Map yet... My app is Crashing and not even showing an Emply Fragment.. I just want my app to Show this Fragment

Comment: `Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` means that you've probably not added the support library correctly. I'd suggest you use Android Studio since Eclipse is no longer officially supported. If you have to use eclipse look for questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project - ps  "i dont get the proper methord to put logcat" the whole thing you've put is perfect. That tells the most.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the map fragment in code.  You'll probably need to use it later anyway.  Change your xml to use a FrameLayout instead

```
mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
         getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mapFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit(); 


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: Do u want me to use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout??

It didnt worked :(

Comment: yeah sorry,  you can use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout, but FrameLayout will be better for performance.

Comment: It didnt make any Difference but Thanks Anyway..:)