# how i can set image from php server in android?

Tags: php, android, json

Actually i can easily get the textView from my server by using setText. i dont know how to set image from server.

`image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);`

and i get string of that image

```
profileimage = jsonObj.getString("profile_img");
```

then i used setImageBitmap to set image.

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(profileimage, 0);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,0, null);
image.setImageBitmap(b);
```

its not displaying by using . need a solution.
 i am using android eclipse.

Comment: use glide library https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to know about [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html.)
, Its a class that is used to decode local file. And by local i mean which are reside in device internal or sd card storage .
And here you need to load a image from cloud with a Url . So you need to download that image first then get Bitmap from it and then set it to image view . This is a often task so some great developers already made a bunch of libraries for this purpose to make it bread and butter for us .
Below are some references you can use Its easy and optimized :

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

[Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)

Comment: i am using eclipse how can solve this ?? need a brief steps  if u please.

Comment: There is no issue with IDE whether you are using eclipse or AS . Each IDE has its own Build method . To add those library in eclipse you need to download the project or you can look for a .jar. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643015/4168607) will help for further steps. Suggesting you to use Android Studio for android development .

Comment: okay but i dont know to download the image and getting bitmap from it. help me ADM :) i am new android developer

Comment: Use Glide library and follow the answer below by Rasoul Miri or read about the glide on github .

Answer (score 1):

may be this will help you,

add this library in your build gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

than your activity,

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(profileimage).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for image loading. Sample code using Picasso looks like `Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

1.esay setup
2.image to memory and do the cache
3.optimize images for size ImageView

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default)
        .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .fit()
        .centerCrop()
        .into(imageView);



Glide.with(context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default) 
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) 
        .fitCenter()
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: if i done using glide i can dowload the image and it il cache or not ??? still not problem solved.