# I want to translate english text to hindi using following API

Tags: java, android, google-translate

**Following is my TextActivity**

```
package com.ds.texar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class TextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private String textFromMain = "";
    ToggleButton languageToggleButton;
    private String outputHindiString = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //setting text string received from main activity
        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mtextview);
        textFromMain = getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext");
        textView.setText(textFromMain);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener(){
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });

        languageToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.language_toggle_button);
        languageToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(languageToggleButton.isChecked()){
                        try {
                            Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://android-er.blogspot.com/");
                            outputHindiString = Translate.execute(textFromMain,
                                    Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            outputHindiString = "Error";
                        }
                        textView.setText(outputHindiString);
                }
                else{
                    textView.setText(textFromMain);
                }
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton copyText = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.copy_text);
        copyText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("myText", textFromMain);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Your text copied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP| Gravity.LEFT, 10, 300);
//                toast.show();
            }
        });

        final FloatingActionButton textToSpeechButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.text_to_speech);
        textToSpeechButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textFromMain, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textToSpeech.speak(textFromMain, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        if(textToSpeech !=null){
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Here is Layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ds.texar.TextActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/content_text" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/text_to_speech"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_silent_mode_off" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/copy_text"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include2"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeCopyDrawable" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/language_toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/check"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include2"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ds.texar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.light" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TextActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_text"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error log:

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
 :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies,
 :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources,
 :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
 C:\Users\DELL_PC\Desktop\Texar\app\src\main\java\com\ds\texar\TextActivity.java
 Error:(16, 32) error: package com.google.api.translate does not exist
 Error:(17, 32) error: package com.google.api.translate does not exist
 Error:(58, 29) error: cannot find symbol variable Translate Error:(60,
 37) error: cannot find symbol variable Language Error:(60, 55) error:
 cannot find symbol variable Language Error:(59, 49) error: cannot find
 symbol variable Translate Error:Execution failed for task
 ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 6.836 secs
 Information:7 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
 output in console
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Download jar file from `http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/.`

- Import it in current project folder.
- Import jar into eclipse
- Right-click on the project & select Properties.
- Select Java Build Path.
- Select the Libraries tab.
- Click the Add External JARs button.
- Find the path to your JAR and add it.

Comment: I'm using Android studio and I'm beginner to android so can you please help me how to use  .jar in Android Studio.

Comment: You need to import the jar into project in which it is needed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project   use this to import jar into the project.