# unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/shaded/apache/log4j/Logger;) after upgrading Firebase for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, firebase

When I save into Firebase data storage, I am getting the following errors but the email and password registration is fine in the login&auth section. I am using Java, Android. I already spent 3 hours but cannot fix problems (Maybe the new firebase android update?).

Here is proof that email/pass is working:

```
            Firebase f = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/"); 
            Firebase userData = f.child("User");
            //save into login&auth of email and password SUCCESS
            userData.createUser(emailAddr.getText().toString(), passwd.getText().toString(), new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    // there was an error
                }
            });

            Firebase set_user = userData.push();
            String user_id = set_user.getKey();
            //save into database FAILED
            Map<String, Object> save_user = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            save_user.put("disp_name", dispName.getText().toString());
            save_user.put("real_name", rl_name.getText().toString());
            save_user.put("email_addr", emailAddr.getText().toString());
            save_user.put("user_pwd", passwd.getText().toString());
            save_user.put("id",user_id);
            set_user.setValue(save_user);
```

[image]

The following are errors I get from running the code above.

> VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/shaded/apache/log4j/Logger;)

and

> VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 26177: Lorg/shaded/apache/log4j/Category;.log (Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/shaded/apache/log4j/Priority;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

and

> Could not find method org.shaded.apache.log4j.Category.log, referenced from method org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.trace

and

> VFY: unable to resolve static field 9561 (WARN) in Lorg/shaded/apache/log4j/Priority;

Comment: I just recheck and IT DOES WORK on a different url but my main url is broken....

Comment: I think its latest update might have broken my app, I just created a new one and change the url everything is normal now... :( I think I was pretty lucky my project is not a complete one.

Comment: It looks like you're either missing log4j or have the wrong version of that library. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123118/upgrading-android-sdk-causes-java-lang-verifyerror-crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These warnings are from the shaded version of the Apache httpclient library Firebase includes and only affect logging which is disabled by default. They are caused by reflection not working together with shading. However they should not prevent the Firebase library from working and you can ignore these warnings for now.

Comment: yes, my database was affected but these warnings are un-related.