# Android Support Library V4 XML

Tags: android, xml

I have imported android support v4 library, in Java it works fine, but when i tried to use it in xml, it gave me Error in an **XML file: aborting build.**, so i cant do this in my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried adding library to build path and many others methods, but i still have problem. Can you help me guys?

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure to put the `jar` in the `libs` folder in your project?
See this SO post for an explanation: [Android: What is the folder name of the jar files (LIB or LIBS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185488/android-what-is-the-folder-name-of-the-jar-files-lib-or-libs)

Comment: Yeah, LIBS, but it's not working, i'm adding it as library, and making clean, but nothing's happen

Comment: When you say `Library` do you mean in the `Android` option under `Properties` of your project or as a `jar` in your build path? You want to make it a jar, not a library.

Comment: I put androidsupportv4.jar in libs>>Configure Build Path>>Library>> Add Jars I tried Right Click>> Add to Build Path too

Comment: Then something else is happening. Can you post the entire XML document? Chances are its got more to do than just the `ViewPager`

Comment: defualt main.xml, or other, everywhere, but in java code it works fine

Comment: The rest of the XML file you showed the snippet of above. Which ever file that is, if its `main.xml` then that one...

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>`

Comment: In Intelleji Idea it works fine in xml, but i want wark in Eclipse

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Any chance you can post your `.classpath` file?

Comment: Where i can find it? Ok, i will post

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/android-support-v4.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
`

Comment: Hmm. so that looks good to me. Yeah I'm out of ideas - sorry :(