# Android: changing the location of jar library causes "Unfortunately, app has stopped" OK. How to fix?

Tags: android

I simply added a jar library to `project/libs`. The app is working very well.
 I decided to change its location; I first deleted it, and added it again to the root of the project (instead of project/libs) . I also added it to the `Java Build Path`
 But in this case, when running the app it shows a message saying **"Unfortunately, app has stopped"**. 
When I reinstated the jar library to its previous location The app is working.

How to change the location of jar library and get the app work?

Comment: Put... the candle... back.

Comment: HAHAHA, yeah you will need to modify the build script or put it back in the lib folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the normal build process to work, they have to be in `libs`. It's how ADT works. It's erroring because those jars are not being exported to your build.

See here:
[Android: What is the folder name of the jar files (LIB or LIBS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185488/android-what-is-the-folder-name-of-the-jar-files-lib-or-libs)

If you want to customise it you can but you may have to build via Ant.

See here: [How do I reference external jar files in a common directory (not libs) to build android project using ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312478/how-do-i-reference-external-jar-files-in-a-common-directory-not-libs-to-build)