# How do I use classes I got from JAR in Android?

Tags: java, android, jar

I'm trying to make a Java server and an Android client to send Objects to each other.

First, I made a package called PacketSets, which will contain many classes which can be sent through the ObjectInput or OutputStream. I made the PacketSets as a JAR file.

Second, I added the PacketSets.jar to my java server which is working just fine. I added it to it's build path.

Third, using the same method, I tried to put the Jar to my Android client, and it just doesn't work as it did on the Java server.

It somehow can't seem to even recognize the JAR file, even though the JAR file is added to it's Referenced Library folder. For example, there's a class called Packet inside the JAR, and such statement like "Packet p = new Packet();" should work. But it doesn't. It keeps on saying that " Packet cannot be resolved to a type."

Why is this happening? The server, as I've metioned above works just fine. Is there any additional works to get this going on android? For a total hour, it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your JAR in the libs folder of the Android project. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185488/android-what-is-the-folder-name-of-the-jar-files-lib-or-libs) for more information.

Comment: I tried the method on that thread but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Will this be some issues concerned about package settings? The Java server uses a default package, and the Android doesn't.

Comment: A regular Java SE JAR should work just fine. There are some libraries which are excluded in the Android runtime like the RMI stuff. Do you use any of that? Another problem could be Eclipse. Sometimes it's just broken and needs a restart.