# Project messed up, cloned from repo now ClassNotFoundExceptions

Tags: android

My project got messed up so I started over by just cloning from my repo. After getting all dependencies in order, I tried running my app and it crashes from:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.me.app.activities.Main in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.me-1.apk]
```

The class is there, its in the Manifest, everything is good. What can I do?! I feel like my app is burning in flames now!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are several possibilities that could have caused this.

- Use of the android name attribute in the manifest, incorrect activity naming convention, .project file corruption, accidentally unchecking "Project -> Build Automatically": [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app)
- Incorrect (or inconsistent) package naming: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880489/android-classnotfoundexception)
- Incorrect class loader context: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090009/classnotfoundexception-android)

Also you might find ideas on the [Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/JC7_qqwBRjo).

Each of these has additional ideas and debugging attempts through the thread responses and comments.

If none of these work for you let us know and maybe we can find a new cause.