# It got the 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' error when run the export apk

Tags: android

I write a android app in Eclipse and use run command on my cellphone.

It's run success on my cellphone.

But I use [Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package...] to export my app.

Then use [adb install] to install apk on my cellphone and run.

And I got the error message:

```
07-22 11:20:43.537: E/AndroidRuntime(20216): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mytest.MyActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mytest-1.apk]
```

In [Java Build Path -> Order and Export], I have been selected all.

In AndroidManifest.xml, the application attribute doesn't have android:name.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

I'm success use Eclipse run on my cellphone, why run error when I export the app?

please help me, thanks!!

Comment: are you using progaurd? if yes disable and make a signed apk n try

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use progaurd.

Comment: Just wanted to get this in in case it helps others. I got this fixed for me by fixing my android project properties. **Right click on your project -> Android tools -> fix project properties**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to multiple reasons for this happening from what I have researched. Do you have a lib folder? if so change it to "libs".

Do you have proguard enabled? If so that may cause the problem.
Also try unchecking the "Android #.#.#" and "Android Dependencies" in your Build Path, Order and Export.

Check out this thread which has a bunch of other possible solutions, a lot of them deal with setting the proper ActivityName in the manifest file.
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on working app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app)

If those solutions still don't solve the problem try these threads.

[Android: Unable to instantiate activity / ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820554/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-classnotfoundexception)

[ClassNotFoundException Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090009/classnotfoundexception-android)

Comment: Thanks for your help~~
I'm updating my SDK Tools(Rev. 20) and SDK Platform-tools(Rev. 12) and ADT, then solved.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue, after 2 hours of research I managed to fix this problem by deleting "bin" and "gen" folders and rebuilding project.

Comment: where are these folders located?

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do is just re-do the building/exporting process with no modification to the code whatsoever. It worked for me, which I did was to export it two times.
On my first export, the build APK has lower file size and the second export (with no any modification to the code/configuration) produced a slightly larger file size (about 200KB diff).

This bug in building is really costly, kills you in front of your manager, and should be really fixed by Android/Eclipse team. Kind of sucks